# I want to write a python programme that does repeated multiplication

Tags: python, for-loop, multiplication

A programme that asks the user to enter a number, multiply it by 2, and multiply the answer by 2, and so on, as many times as you want

- Lets say the number is 100
- Expected result
- 100×2= 200
- 200×2=400
- 400×2=800
- 800×2=1600,
- and as many times i want

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: You should use recursivity

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
number = input("What number?")
iteration = input("How many times?")
for i in range(iteration):
    new_number = number * 2
    print(new_number)
    number = new_number
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: You are right. My bad :o

Comment: *input()* returns a string which you then pass to *range()* which will then induce a TypeError exception as will your attempt to multiply two strings